# Oracle SQL Conditional Arithmetic

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

I have a data set that lists an employee id, code, hours and wages. Any 1 employee can have 1 of either OT1 or OT2, or they could have 1 row of both. The short of it is that I need to sum all of the wages, but if they have both codes to just take the amount for OT1. Then I want to divide total wages by the hours in the condition I stated. Example Data:

```
+ -------+------+-------+--------+
| ID     | CODE | HOURS | AMOUNT |
+ -------+------+-------+--------+
| 123456 | OT1  | 10    | 80     |
| 789000 | OT1  | 8     | 120    |
| 789000 | OT2  | 8     | 60     |
| 654111 | OT2  | 4     | 40     |
+ -------+------+-------+--------+
```

I'm attempting to add a new column to divide the amount by the hours and will remove the code column so we can sum each employee to have a single record. The catch is, if the employee has both OT1 and OT2, I don't want to sum those , I just want the hours from OT1. That logic manually applied to my previous example

```
+ -------+-------+--------+---------+
| ID     | HOURS | AMOUNT | AVERAGE |
+ -------+-------+--------+---------+
| 123456 | 10    | 80     | 8       |
| 789000 | 8     | 180    | 22.5    |
| 654111 | 4     | 40     | 10      |
+ -------+-------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: show us your sql code  ..

Comment: The `HOURS` column does not belong in your output, I think.  Either remove it, or explain to us what it is doing there.

Comment: SELECT
ID,
CODE,
SUM(HOURS),
SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM data_set
GROUP BY ID, CODE

I need the hours in the output for the end user to see. It's essentially sum(amount) / first occurrence of hours per ID

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can fix it just by not summing the hours column and grouping by it instead. Supposedly from the data entry user if they have multiple codes they always have the same hours in each.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer incase someone wants to solve this more intutivley in the case where the hours in OT1 are different from OT2. But for my example data and needs grouping the hours, summing the amount in a CTE and then applying the arithmetic works

WITH data_set AS
(
SELECT
ID,
HOURS,
SUM(AMOUNT) AS "AMOUNT",
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY ID, HOURS
)
SELECT ID, HOURS, SUM(amount) AS "AMOUNT", ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT)/HOURS,2)
FROM data_set
GROUP BY ID, HOURS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(sum(case when code = 'OT1' then hours end),
                sum(hours)
               ) as hours,
       sum(amount) as amount,
       (sum(amount) / 
        coalesce(sum(case when code = 'OT1' then hours end),
                 sum(hours)
               )
       ) as average
from t
group by id
order by id;
```

This method explicitly combines values from multiple rows, so it should work as expected if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You get the hours for the first code with Oracle's `KEEP FIRST`:

```
select
  id, 
  min(hours) keep (dense_rank first order by code) as hours,
  sum(amount) as amount,
  round(sum(amount) / min(hours) keep (dense_rank first order by code), 2) as average
from mytable
group by id
order by id;
```